# How can we remove bad tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm cleaning up the [vb](/questions/tagged/vb) tag, as it is ambiguous. Questions tagged `vb` would be better off tagged one of `vba`, `vbscript`, `vb6` (and rarely an older version), or `vb.net` instead.  However, there are a couple tag synonyms that point to vb: `visual-basic` and `microsoft.visualbasic`, which will make this difficult.

The latter synonym especially troubles me, as it's just plain wrong. Microsoft.VisualBasic is a specific namespace included with the core .Net Framework, and isn't in any way limited to VB.Net. I suspect a large number of the the questions originally tagged `Microsoft.VisualBasic` are actually from people asking about using this namespace from C#, and have nothing to do with `vb` at all.

I looked, and I didn't see an obvious way to suggest this synonym be removed.  This can't be the only bad synonym. Indeed, a search here on meta showed several other questions about bad synonyms, with no way to remove them aside from moderator/developer intervention. Can we have a way to nominate tag synonyms for removal?

Comment: I removed the synonym that was just plain wrong.  How does the other synonym make clean-up difficult?  Do you mean that just in the general case where you might not know what other synonyms to look for?

Comment: It makes it difficult because the end goal of my cleanup is that there be no questions left at all tagged vb. This is desirable because at that point most users lose the ability to use the tag at all, and those who can still use it tend to know better. Since the tag is mainly an ambiguous distraction from better tags, this is a good thing. Even when users try to use the tag and bump into the limitation, the main result is that they learn something about better tagging. If there is a synonym pointing to vb, it's more likely that the tag will be re-created.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I removed the other synonym as well.  Also, I edited your post to say that modertors can remove synonyms, but it's worth noting that it does take a developer to permanently block a tag from being recreated.

Comment: Do you still want the feature request? Seems to me like this situation is infrequent enough that mods should be able to handle it on a case-by-case basis, and tag synonym change requests do benefit from the discussion and exposure they get here.

Comment: @BilltheLizard it is also worth noting that we do not have a mechanism to outright block tag synonym pairs, on rare occasion I have needed that

Comment: I feel the feature request is a tad too rare to be needed, we only get one of these every few weeks

Comment: Demoted to discussion